# What's the max limit for document libraries in a Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, limitations

I can find TechNet articles on the software boundaries for SharePoint Online, but there is no mention on the maximum number of lists or libraries. Any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no limit mentioned for number of list /library in a site collection but we can do a math and estimate how much we can create a web application.

Supported Limit for **number Items** in a **content Database** is **60 Million**.

Supported limit for **Number of Items** in a **List / library** is **30 Million**.

Now if we have a single site collection in a content database then we can 2 have List / Library with 30 Million items in each. Again you can cross that limit per depend upon your infrastructure.

Number of list ? library depend on the following factor

- How many Site collection in a single content database.
- How many items in each list and library.
- Performance of the SharePoint.

another example: a single site collection in a content database, can have 60 list with 1 million items in each.