# Libraries limit in root site collection SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, limitations, boundaries

I have a requirement to provision a library for each employee in the company if not already exists. Total number of employee are 55000. Is it safe to create those many libraries in the root site collection?

I find all information about everything except number of libraries here. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt842345.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-online-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498

thanks
-Praveen.

Comment: But why? In place of the p drive?

Comment: Have you considered using OneDrives? There were designed for per-employee use.

Answer (score 0):

"Waqas Sarwar" had answered this question in another post.

[What's the max limit for document libraries in a Site Collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231637/whats-the-max-limit-for-document-libraries-in-a-site-collection)

There are no limit mentioned for number of list/library in a site collection but we can do a math and estimate how much we can create a web application.

Supported Limit for number Items in a content Database is 60 Million.

Supported limit for Number of Items in a List/library is 30 Million.

Now if we have a single site collection in a content database then we can 2 have List / Library with 30 Million items in each. Again you can cross that limit per depend upon your infrastructure.

Number of list ? library depend on the following factor:

1. How many Site collection in a single content database.
2. How many items in each list and library.
3. Performance of the SharePoint.

Another example: a single site collection in a content database, can have 60 list with 1 million items in each.

Below article is about the maximum number of lists in SharePoint, although it is talking about list, but I think it is useful to you:

[Maximum number of lists in Sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66652/maximum-number-of-lists-in-sharepoint)

As a result, you need to consider your own situation and then make a choice.